Developing kivy android app using buildozer.spec with FCM implementation and having error
Below is the error I am getting, when I go to the below location so I find this directory arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21 and after that I can see kivy file but below is location is not available I try to clean and rebuild but still the problem is same. please help
[INFO]:    -> directory context /mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/kivy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main

    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1256, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 685, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 104, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 163, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 497, in build_recipes
    recipe.apply_patches(arch)

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/mnt/d/app_linux/FCM_LINUX/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/other_builds/kivy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy'

